# Map doesn't display using folium choropleth map for zip codes

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I am trying to use folium to create a map with zip codes showing. However I can't seem to get any results displayed - there are no errors, but I don't get any output. The html just returns a map. What could be the issue?
Here's my test code below:

```
import pandas as pd
shelters = pd.read_csv('LAzipcodes.csv')

import json, requests
response = requests.get("https://maps.lacity.org/lahub/rest/services/Boundaries/MapServer/26/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=ZIPCODE&outSR=4326&f=json")
data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))

lazipcodes = []
for i in range(len(data['features'])):
    if data['features'][i]['attributes']['ZIPCODE'] in list(shelters['ZIP'].astype(str).unique()):
        lazipcodes.append(data['features'][i])
#print(len(lazipcodes))

new_json = dict.fromkeys(['type','features'])
new_json['type'] = 'FeatureCollection'
new_json['features'] = lazipcodes

open('la-county-zipcodes.json', "w").write(
    json.dumps(new_json, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',',':'))
)

la_zip = r'la-county-zipcodes.json'

import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[34.0522, -118.2437], zoom_start=11)
m.choropleth(
    geo_data = la_zip,
    data = shelters,
    columns = ['ZIP','COUNT'],
    key_on = 'feature.attributes.ZIPCODE',
    fill_color = 'YlGn',
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    line_opacity = 0.2,
    line_color='Blue',
    legend_name = 'Count Rate'     
    )

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save('Zipcodes.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is converting with different types of geojson files, but is the geometry information missing? Also folium.Choropleth(...). .add_to(m) is the correct setting, I got the zipdoce geojson from [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/content/learn/projects/wave_charts_custom_map/wave_charts_custom_map_geojson) and was able to draw a choropleth map by creating sample data.

```
import json

geojson = open('./data/la-zip-code-areas-2012.geojson', 'r')
data = json.load(geojson)

lazipcodes = []
for i in range(len(data['features'])):
    zip_code = data['features'][i]['properties']['name']
    lazipcodes.append(zip_code)

shelters = pd.DataFrame({'ZIP':lazipcodes, 'COUNT': np.random.randint(0,100, len(lazipcodes))})

import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[34.0522, -118.2437], zoom_start=8)
folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = data,
    data = shelters,
    columns = ['ZIP','COUNT'],
    key_on = 'feature.properties.name',
    fill_color = 'YlGn',
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    line_opacity = 0.2,
    line_color = 'Blue',
    legend_name = 'Count Rate'     
    ).add_to(m)

# folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
# m.save('Zipcodes.html')

m
```

[image]